# Two git repos with same folder structure/names in one directory?

Tags: git

I've already searched and found many answers regarding that topic (submodule, subtree,...) but I don't really know which is the 'best solution' for my specific problem having two repos in one directory **when both repos share the same folder structure/names**.

So my partner and I code together on some specific files. Our repo (on github) have the following folder structure.

```
├───AddOns
│       └───SidiFolder2
│           <file.cs>
│   <file2.cs>
│   <file4.cs>
│   <file5.cs>
├───Indicators
│   ├───Sidi
│   │   └───SidiFolder2
│   │       <file.cs>
```

These folders/files are locally stored in default vs2022 source folder at the moment (%USERPROFILE%\source\Repos\OurName\OurProject).

Beside that there is a 'big directory' in %USERPROFILE%\DOCUMENTS\LOCALFOLDER\* which I also have source controlled with/to github (only for me - no other person has access to that one).

My problem now is this LOCALFOLDER has some folders in it which we also use/have in our repo mentioned at top.

So please have a look at the structure below.
I have this 'big' (private) repo on github (only for me - no one should see/use those folders/files) and we have a 'small' repo on github which my partner and I use for coding where at the end a few folders/files have to be placed in the 'big' LOCALFOLDER structure.
So all the folder/files marked with "⋘⋘⋘⋘" should be used from our 'small' repo.

Both repos should be manageable for me in visual studio comm. edition 2022 (with git ui tools there if possible).

What I've read `git submodule` or `git subtree` are only possible if they are located in its own/extra folder (which isn't the case here, also subtree is still not manageable with vs2022 git ui possibilities).

```
├───AddOns ⋘⋘⋘⋘
│       └───SidiFolder2 ⋘⋘⋘⋘
│           <file.cs> ⋘⋘⋘⋘
│   <file1.cs>
│   <file2.cs> ⋘⋘⋘⋘
│   <file3.cs>
│   <file4.cs> ⋘⋘⋘⋘
│   <file5.cs> ⋘⋘⋘⋘
│   <other_files_here.cs>
├───BarsTypes
├───bin
├───ChartStyles
├───de-DE
├───DrawingTools
│   └───Sidi
├───es-ES
├───ExportNinjaScript
├───fr-FR
├───ImportTypes
├───Indicators ⋘⋘⋘⋘
│   ├───AB
│   ├───GB
│   ├───Settlement
│   ├───Sidi ⋘⋘⋘⋘
│   │   └───SidiFolder2 ⋘⋘⋘⋘
│   │       <file.cs> ⋘⋘⋘⋘
│   ├───CD
│   └───EF
│   └───GH
│   <many_files_here.cs>
│   <many_files_here2.cs>
├───it-IT
├───ko-KR
├───MarketAnalyzerColumns
├───OptimizationFitnesses
├───Optimizers
├───PerformanceMetrics
├───pt-PT
├───ru-RU
├───ShareServices
├───Strategies
├───SuperDomColumns
└───zh-Hans
```

Comment: "*I have this 'big' (private) repo on github (only for me - no one should see/use those folders/files) and we have a 'small' repo on github which my partner and I use for coding where at the end a few folders/files have to be placed in the 'big' LOCALFOLDER structure.*" This is a strange set up. Could you explain why you're doing this? It sounds like this would be better solved by configuration management or branches or release management. What is the relationship of the "small common" repo to the "big private" repos?

Comment: The 'big private' is a given structure from an installed software we both (me and my partner have isntalled) and isn't 1:1 the same for us both. He has his own bought / coded files in there which do not tackle me - so do I have files in there only for me.

My partner has the 'big private' in his own private repo on github - so do I.

Comment: We both work on the mentioned 'small common repo' where we pull/push our codes.

When using branches we have access problems, haven't we?

More and more I come to to the decision that managing our 'small common' repo outside of the 'big localfolder structure' is the easiest in combination with two simple batch scripts which copies our needed ~10 files from 'small' to 'big' or the other way round. 

Last one because coding in visual studio is done with the 'big' project open so we have to 'copy back' the edited files to the 'small' folder and commit/merge/push/pull from t

Comment: It sounds like what you have is a shared, common framework and then your own individual add-ons and customizations. But you don't have a clear boundary between them. It would be better to treat the shared code as something entirely separate which you work on and package and install separately from everything else. The shared code ***should not*** live in the same repo as the add-ons and customizations. You ***should not*** be altering the shared code and copying it back. If you need changes to the shared code, clone that repo, do the work, push it, and install it.

Answer (score 1):

`git submodule` and `git subtree` are indeed two alternative setups when dealing with a ["monorepo"](https://www.atlassian.com/fr/git/tutorials/monorepos) − a big repository aggregating several different projects… that can have their own history upstream.

Two remarks:

- `git subtree` is much more lightweight than `git submodule`, so if you have the choice between both approaches, I would straightforwardly recommend relying on [`git subtree`](https://www.atlassian.com/fr/git/tutorials/git-subtree).
- as you pointed out, both approaches require that the "common files" are located in a single subfolder.

As a result, if you cannot use `git subtree` as is, you should either refactor the layout of your repositories (at least to separate the shared files from private files in different subfolders), or devising some "handcrafted" Bash-or-Powershell scripts to help you automating the sync…

Alternatively, you may want to try an [interesting combination](https://germano.dev/dotfiles/) of these 2 git extensions: [vcsh](https://github.com/RichiH/vcsh) and [myrepos](https://myrepos.branchable.com/). Albeit the documented use case is a bit different than yours (managing one's *dotfiles*…)

Otherwise as [suggested by @Schwern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71864400/two-git-repos-with-same-folder-structure-names-in-one-directory/71864536#comment126993030_71864400), maybe you would just need to rely on `git branch`es management?